# Find an object based on its absolute_url given a urlconf

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have the following get_absolute_url defined in my model.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return "/products/category/type/%d%s%d" % (self.owner.id,
      self.owner, self.id)
```

I have the following urlconf defined in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^products/category/type/(\w+)(\w+)(\w+)/$', 'detail'),
```

In the 'detail' method within views.py, how do I refer to an instance of the Product object using it's get_absolute_url?

I'm new at this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/

Comment: Would you happen to know where in the documentation I can find it? I've looked at it over and over and I can't pinpoint the spot.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "find" or "refer" to an object given its absolute_url. What exactly do you mean? What are you hoping to achieve? What do you have so far?

Comment: To clarify: I defined get_absolute_url within my model. Each instance of the model will have a unique absolute url. Now, I'm trying to display an instance of the object in another page -- in the views.py file, can I "get" that instance of that object using the absolute url as a "filter" of sorts?

Comment: I just don't understand what the absolute URL has to do with anything. Do you mean in the view referred to by that URL, you want to display the actual object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that what you actually want to do is simply get the relevant object in the `detail` view.

But first, a word of warning: your URL is very strange and won't give you the result you expect. You have no division between the values of owner id, owner, and id, so the regex will *always* allocate all the characters up to the last two as owner id, and one each to owner and id. For example, if your URL was `products/category/type/1daniel34/`, instead of being parsed as `('1', 'daniel', '34')` this would always be parsed as `('1daniel', '3', '4')`. You should put a slash between each element to be captured, use `\d` instead of `\w` to match digits, and use named groups:

```
^products/category/type/(?P<owner_id>\d+)/(?P<owner>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/$
```

(Also, you should consider using [the `permalink` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.permalink) to produce your absolute URL, rather than reproducing the whole string from the urlconf.)

Now, the point of a view is that it is passed the values captured from the URL conf. So your reference to the absolute URL is confusing: there's no reason to care about the value produced by get_absolute_url, you simply have to query the database using the values you are passed in the view. In this case, your view would look something like this:

```
def detail(owner_id, owner, id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id, owner_id=owner_id)
    ...etc...
```

Note that I've left out the reference to `owner`, as it seems likely that the owner ID is enough to identify the object. In fact, I would say that the id itself is enough, since it is unique, and you don't need the owner at all: but that's up to you to decide.

Comment: thanks for the help! my original plan was to use the absolute url as an id-key of sorts so i could get the object in the view using the absolute url as a filter of sorts. I realize now there may be better ways to handle that though.